calcAmountOut SOLANA RAYDIUM
Hello how can i calcul amountOut of a swap on solana raydium please ?
This is the code i try :
 const poolInfo = await Liquidity.fetchInfo({
  connection: raydiumSwap.connection,
  poolKeys: poolKeys,
});
const amountOut = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
          poolKeys,
          poolInfo,
          amountIn: '5000000',
          currencyOut: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
          slippage : '5',
        }).amountOut;
console.log(amountOut);


How is this code not meeting your expectations?

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/15841/how-to-get-amountout-of-a-swap-on-raydium-solana-please
This is the asking question
